# Running multiple commands as root with Jsch()

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Im having problems running multiple commands as the root user, using the **exec** channel. I dont get any exceptions, however the second command is not being executed for some reason.

Here is my code

```
try {
  JSch jsch = new JSch();

  String command1 = "touch 1.txt; touch 2.txt";
            //"sudo chmod 755 script.sh; sudo sh script.sh";
  String user = "user";
  String host = "10.68.228.140";
  String privateKey = "/home/user/.ssh/blabla";

  jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
  System.out.println("identity added ");


  Session session = null;
  while(session == null) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
  }
  System.out.println("session created ");

  java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
  config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setConfig(config);

  while(!session.isConnected()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    session.connect();
  }

  System.out.println("session connected.....");

  Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;

  sftpChannel.put("/home/user/script.sh", "/home/user");
  sftpChannel.disconnect();
  channel.disconnect();

  Channel channel1 = session.openChannel("exec");
  ((ChannelExec) channel1).setCommand(command);
  channel1.connect();
  channel1.disconnect();

  session.disconnect();

} catch(JSchException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(SftpException se){
    se.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e) {

}
```

So if I leave it like this, everything is fine. The two files are created on the remote machine. But if I give as command the commented line, then the script is not executed. (It changes only mode)
Could you give me a help please? I've been stuck with this all day now.

Comment: Does the command (`sudo ...`) work if you execute it in a terminal?

Comment: Yes, its working from a terminal..

Comment: And did you try it from a non-interactive terminal? E.g. in PuTTY go to *Connection > SSH > TTY* and check *Don't allocate a pseudo terminal*.

Comment: No I didnt.. Both my local machine and the remote have Linux.. So I ssh from my local to the remote from a terminal.

Comment: For `ssh`, the equivalent option is `-t`, so try `ssh -t user@host "sudo chmod 755 script.sh; sudo sh script.sh"`

Comment: Yes, its working from the terminal with the above command..

Comment: With the same account?

Comment: yes the same account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74255/discussion-between-stanos-and-martin-prikryl).